# jquery callback with php.... just want the value, not redirect

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, redirect, callback

I thought this was going to be rather simple but I'm a bit rusty.

I call this javascript/jquery code:

```
$.get("plugin.php", {up_vote:surl},
    function(data){
    //alert(data);
    document.getElementById('numvotes').innerHTML = data;
});
......
```

And when it returns I get the value, which is some number that is returned as a string, then right after the number a long text about redirecting is displayed. How do I get rid of that? I just want the value.
Here is what is returned:
8    (if you are not redirected after 10 seconds, please click here)

What is causing this to redirect? Or, how do I just get rid of that '(if you are ....) text?

Comment: data = data.match(/^\d{1,}/);
document.getElementById('numvotes').innerHTML = data;

This combination worked! For some reason, the regex did not work with jquery, and the jquery $('#numvotes")... would just display the text for a few seconds then disappear.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually your plugin.php sending the redirect text (and probably some other html too). Try to browse directly to plugin.php?up_vote=surl and you'll see what happens.

Furthermore, if you are using jquery anyway, why not change `document.getElementById()` to:

```
$('#numvotes').html(data);
```

Comment: thank you. As mentioned below, the jquery representation disappears after a few seconds (strangely) and also displays all the same stuff. Thanks for the tip on opening up plugin.php directly. Shoulda thoughta that!

Answer (score 1):

You could try using

```
data = data.match(/^\d{1,}/);  
$('#numvotes').html(data);
```

if the result is always going to be in the same format that you gave in your question.

Comment: did that. same thing and then it suddenly disappears after a few seconds, making it two problems to fix.

Comment: Now that looks like bubble gum and paper mache... my kinda fix right now. Thank you. UPDATE - Didn't work. The regex does something, so that means that giorgio is probably correct, it's a data type issue.